# ARM Cortex M4 GPIO Ports

Tags: arm, microcontroller, cortex-m

I am working with a Cortex-M4 processor and am confused about a question regarding GPIO memory associations.

So there are 8 bits for each memory mapped register. For the GPIO PORTE, there must also be 8 bits associated with it. However, there are only 6 pins (PE0-PE5) associated with PORTE. What exactly is in the other two bits? And what would they be titled?

I apologize if this question is unclear.

Comment: What particular type of device do you use?

Answer (score 0):

The other two bits can be anything depending on what documentations says, usually they can be ***reserved*** but also can be assigned to other functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This depends greatly on hardware.  But generalizing a bit most of these controllers multiplex the output pins so that they can be configured to perform functions depending on your application.